# Identifying some LEGO figures

Tags: set-identification, chima

I just bought my kid these awesome LEGO figures. Can anyone identify them, since we are looking up their building instruction.

Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three of those sets are from "Legends of Chima" series and one is from "Hero Factory".

[CHI Gorzan (70202)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=117963)

[image]

[CHI Fluminox (70211)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=126475)

[image]

[Frost Beast (44011)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=44011-1)

[image]

[CHI Laval (70200)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70200-1)

[image]